# Can you explain the differences between all those ways of passing function to a component?

Tags: reactjs

Just a snippet code in one of React tutorial questions.

What happens when you click each of the buttons?

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor() {
    super(); 
    this.name = 'MyComponent';
    
    this.handleClick2 = this.handleClick1.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleClick1() {
    alert(this.name);
  }
  
  handleClick3 = () => alert(this.name);
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick1()}>click 1</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick1}>click 2</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick2}>click 3</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick3}>click 4</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Why will click 2 work the way it works?

Comment: Look at this. Maybe it will answer your question - https://javascript.info/bind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `this` and classes is one of the harder subjects to wrap your head around. Perhaps it makes it easier to understand with a few examples.

Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9851#issuecomment-306221157) in the React repository. Dan Abramov explains which method Facebook uses internally.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  name = 'MyComponent';

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick4 = this.handleClick4.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick1() {
    // `this` is not the component instance since this function isn't bound to this class instance.
    alert(this.name); // undefined
  }

  handleClick2() {
    // Using arrow functions we force the context to this component instance.
    alert(this.name); // MyComponent
  }

  handleClick3 = () => {
    // Instead of using class methods, we assign an Arrow function to as a member of this class instance.
    // Since arrow functions are bound automatically to the current context, it's bound to this class instance.
    alert(this.name); // MyComponent
  };

  handleClick4() {
    // We are actually overriding this property with a "bound" version of this method in the constructor.
    alert(this.name); // MyComponent
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick1}>click 1</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick2}>click 2</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick3}>click 3</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick4}>click 4</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```