# React Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I get the following error when trying to compile my app `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined`.

I'm having trouble tracking down why  in this line: `if (event.target.getAttribute('name') && !sectionsClicked.includes(event.target.getAttribute('name'))) {` is error

Here is the main react component

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      progressValue: 0,
      sectionsClicked: [],
    };

    this.handleProgress = this.handleProgress.bind(this);
  }


  handleProgress = (event) => {
    const { progressValue } = this.state;
    console.log(progressValue);
    const { sectionsClicked } = this.state;
    if (event.target.getAttribute('name') && !sectionsClicked.includes(event.target.getAttribute('name'))) {
      this.setState({
        progressValue: Math.floor((sectionsClicked.length / 77) * 100),
        sectionsClicked: sectionsClicked.push(event.target.getAttribute('name')),
      });
      console.log(sectionsClicked);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { questions } = this.props;
    const { progressValue } = this.state;
    const groupByList = groupBy(questions.questions, 'type');
    const objectToArray = Object.entries(groupByList);


    return (
      <>
        <Progress value={progressValue} />
        <div className="text-center mt-5">
          <ul>
            {questionListItem && questionListItem.length > 0 ?
              (
                <Wizard
                  onChange={(event) => this.handleProgress(event)}
                  initialValues={{ employed: true }}
                  onSubmit={() => {
                    window.alert('Hello');
                  }}
                >
                  {questionListItem}
                </Wizard>
              ) : null
            }
          </ul>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `Wizard` component?

Comment: @HarishSoni Yes, https://codesandbox.io/s/rj9lwxx89o

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs:

https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form#onchange-formstate-formstate--void

The expected param passed to `onChange` is `formState` not event. Try logging the parameter passed to the function it might have the changes you need.

Answer (score 1):

The `<FormSpy>` component that originally calls `onChange` in `<Wizard>`, which you report upwards to `<App>`, passes a parameter that **is not an event**. It's of type [`FormState`](https://github.com/final-form/final-form#formstate).

On that type, the `target` property is `undefined`, thus the error you're seeing.

If you see the properties of that object in the documentation, you'll probably get what you want by checking the dirty fields of the form, and finding the associated DOM elements.

In all likelihood, though, you can find a way of achieving the desired behavior without resorting to DOM attributes at all. The very same `dirtyFields` property has the names you might be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Also, take a look at your methods and binding. You're actually using three separate approaches to fix the context of your `handleProgress` function.

For more information, look at this answer:

[Can you explain the differences between all those ways of passing function to a component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54110242/can-you-explain-the-differences-between-all-those-ways-of-passing-function-to-a/54110665#54110665)