# This.props undefined in my component and my constructor in well-defined

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, mobile

I'm stuck with a react native problem : I've my component with a (supposed) valid constructor, but I can't access to this.props

In my code :

```js
//In another file
interface mainFunction {
    loaded: () => void,
    disconnect: () => void
}

interface disconnect {
    mainExport:mainFunction
}

class Disconnect extends Component<disconnect> {

    constructor(props:any) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props)
    }

    test() {
        console.log("Disconnect...");
        console.log(this.props);
    }    

    render() {
        return (
            //Some react render
        );
    }

export default Disconnect;
```

When I console log props in my constructor, there are functions that I give to this component, but in my test function this.props is undefined...
I try to set this.props = props in the contructor by props is a readOnly propertie (I use TypeScript)
What did I do wrong ?

**************EDIT**************____
I try to :
create a new attribute to store my function :

```js
class Disconnect extends Component<disconnect> {
    
    disconnect:any

    constructor(props:any) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props.mainExport.disconnect)
        this.disconnect = this.props.mainExport.disconnect
    }
}
```

But this.disconnect is unavariable in my other function

I try to bind my test function in the constructor but it doesn't work too ...

******************ANSWER******************_____
Okay so @Chris got the answer : I need to convert my test method to a variable :

```js
//Old
test() {
        console.log("Disconnect...");
        console.log(this.disconnect_func);
        console.log(this.disconnect);
    }
//New
test = () => {
        console.log("Disconnect...");
        console.log(this.disconnect_func);
        console.log(this.disconnect);
}
```

and it works

Comment: The `test` method is never being called?

Comment: The test method is called by a TouchableHighlight in the render

Comment: SHouldn't you be setting the properties of your component with what is in props? `this.foo = props.foo || 'default';`

Comment: Try binding `this` to `test`, in the constructor: `this.test = this.test.bind(this)`;

Comment: I get a undefined too ...

Comment: But In my constructor this.props work

Comment: It is because the `test` method is being called with a different context (this). You can read the differences here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54110665/1790728. The quick fix is to add binding or make the method an instance variable instead using an arrow function.

Comment: @Chris got the solution ! I need to make this method as a variable. I add it in my question